# Anylogic from "release block" change variable integer

Tags: anylogic

I have an Agent Cart created with 4 variables inside. Each variable is an integer and one of them is called red and has an initial value of 4.

When I use seize/release statement I want change the integer by -1.

In the action section ive tried "On release" saying (Cart)unit.red in hope of changing the variable from 4 to 3.  It gives an error back. "red cannot be resolved or is not a field" along with an syntax error on ")", assignment operator expected in (Cart)unit.red. Writing (Cart)unit.variable doesnt work either. Another sub-question : Is it possible to change two of the variables in the class from the "on release" block?
EDIT
[Classpicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5RHD.jpg)
[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IohAH.jpg)

[Seize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NVgF.jpg)
[Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TVIG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign Cart to your resource pool in order to be able to use it. 
Check this image: 
[image: resourcePool]

After that you need to be very careful on making the distinction between Cart, cart and carts

- Cart being the class
- cart being the agent if there is only 1 cart and you defined it as a single agent
- carts being the population of agents

in your case, only the class is needed if you created a resource type called Cart... check out the capital letters compared to the non-capitalized ones.

Ok, now in your seize block you can use the cart ONLY in the action called on seize unit or on prepare unit.

if you do `((Cart)unit).red=3;` it WILL work, as long as you understood all the previous explanation.

It it doesn't, you will need to give A LOT more information about your model, including very precise images of everything you are doing.

Comment: I have uploaded four images of the situation. It still gives the same mistakes, I want the statement to unit statement to take current inventory level -1, but thats a minor issue. I do not quite understand where the problem lies, and if it were possible I would upload the model. Can you see the mistake from the current images?

Comment: Oh I see why.. you have on your seize to select "units of the same pool" and put carts there... Otherwise things are different

Comment: hmm that did not change the errors. I still have cart cannot be resolved as variable,syntax error on token ")" and red is not a field. I have uploaded the simulation for a day in this link:  https://ufile.io/yn8oq. If I can upload a picture of something at stackoverflow for the information you need instead please tell

Comment: sorry I missed a parenthesis.. it was ((Cart)unit).red=3;

Comment: ahh perfect. Now it seems to work. If I want to "spend" one unit on the seize, can I use the current inventory status -1?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!